# IOS, App Background Running

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create an apps that will pool the data from the server with the time interval 1 minutes.
How can i make my apps to run in background although the apps is close?

Comment: [Read this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app closed is very different from running in backgroud,so I think maybe you just want you app run in backgroud ,so so

you can rewrite the delegate method:

```
   (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
       //...
    }
```

you can not run your app in background if your app closed ,anyway